# Format date of datetime picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I format the date of this? I can format the time easily but not the date.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

It uses the normal datetime from jquery UI.

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
});
```

This one will not work:

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' //This does nothing and does not format the data 
});
```

How do I format the date from this new plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the Date Picker default format.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

This should work since timepicker seems to be wrapping datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

try using this:

```
$('.date').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
});

$('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' //The day format is tied to the datepicker script rather than to the timepicker script
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be setting those at the same time?

```
$('.date').timepicker({    
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' 
});
```

Comment: This does not work. You cannot set the dateFormat in the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
    $('.date').datetimepicker({    
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' 
    });
```